Convex distance on the Boolean cube
The convex distance (or Talagrand distance) can be defined as $\sup_{\alpha}\inf_y d_\alpha(A,x)$, where $d_\alpha$ is the weighted Hamming distance, that is $d_\alpha(x,y)=\sum_{x_i\neq y_i}\alpha_i$, $\alpha$ is a vector of weights, i.e. nonnegative components and unitary Euclidean norm. $A\subseteq\Omega$ is an event, with $\Omega$ and $n$-dimensional probability space, to which $x$ belongs too. Consider $\Omega = \{0,1\}^n$ (the Boolean cube). In The Probabilistic Method (p.117) it is said that in this case the convex distance of $x$ to $A$ coincides with the Eucledian distance of x to the convex hull of $A$.
Here is the thing: if I consider $\{0,1\}^2$ and take $A=\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$ and $x=(1,1)$, then the convex distance is $1$, because whichever $y\in A$ I pick I can just put all the weight of $\alpha$ on the component of $y$ that differs from $x$. So $\alpha=(1,0)$ yields unitary convex distance of $x$ to $A$. But now the convex hull of $A$ is the diagonal joining $(0,1)$ to $(1,0)$, which has length $\sqrt{2}$, and the distance of $(1,1)$ to this diagonal is therefore $\sqrt{2}/2$. Thus the Euclidean distance is not the same as the convex distance. What am I misunderstanding? Thanks for any help.
